# Questões de HTML5

Tags: debate

Andei pesquisando questões de [`HTML5`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5) e percebi que mais da metade das questões que é encontrada realmente não possui nenhum recuso de HTML5 como `Canvas`, `Validação de formulários`, `Controles de áudio e vídeo`, `Drag and Drop` ou API como `Web Storage`, `Web Sockets` e etc...

As pessoas parecem colocar a tag HTML5 pois ficam com receio de colocar apenas HTML e parecer estarem atrasadas? devemos editar as tags dessas questões que não possuem relações com recursos do HTML5 para apenas HTML? ou devemos passar a utilizar apenas HTML5? e esquecer a TAG HTML?

Questões com tags HTML5 que parece não haver nenhum recurso de HTML5

> [Tamanho de linhas de um drop box down quando clicamos no botão "para baixo"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35075/tamanho-de-linhas-de-um-drop-box-down-quando-clicamos-no-bot%C3%A3o-para-baixo)
>
> [Inserção no MySQL com PHP não funciona por nada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34757/inser%C3%A7%C3%A3o-no-mysql-com-php-n%C3%A3o-funciona-por-nada)
>
> [Criar uma div com aparência de balão de quadrinhos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34720/criar-uma-div-com-apar%C3%AAncia-de-bal%C3%A3o-de-quadrinhos)
>
> [Validação de E-mail em form na JSP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34287/valida%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-e-mail-em-form-na-jsp)
>
> [Como criar um link fixo no wordpress?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34072/como-criar-um-link-fixo-no-wordpress)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O ideal é que a *tag* HTML5 seja usada apenas nos casos onde recursos específicos dela são importantes para a pergunta.

Claro que também não precisamos ser absolutamente rígidos e proibir o uso da [html5](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5) onde só há recursos e conceitos mais gerais.

Eu acho que se você tem certeza que a pergunta não tem relação com HTML5, seria interessante  retirar ou trocar a *tag* para representar melhor o que é a pergunta. Devemos lembrar que há casos que não é tão óbvio identificar isto e pode haver desdobramentos que façam a *tag* ser útil ali.

Realmente tem casos de erros absurdos do uso da *tag*.

Comment: Acho que a chave é justamente essa "ter certeza de que **não** tem relação com HTML 5". Se o caso for esse, acredito que o melhor caminho é trocar as tags mesmo.