# Bug de visualizações

Tags: bug, status-nãorepro

Hoje eu estava vendo algumas questões aqui no Meta quando de repente notei o seguinte erro

[image: imagem do erro: 8 votos, 7 acessos]

Como a pergunta pode ter sido **acessada 7 vezes** e ter **8 votos**?

[Pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2092/quest%C3%B5es-de-html5) (mas por algum motivo já está normal)

Comment: Provavelmente a contagem de acessos fica em cache.

Comment: Provavelmente **enquanto** você estava olhando pra pergunta alguém visitou e votou. As atualizações nos votos costumam aparecer imediatamente, mas o número de visualizações só depois que você recarrega a página.